# How to use properties of text boxes outside of the current context in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties

I'm rather new to coding and ran into a small problem. I have a button that creates a new text box every time it's clicked:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point newLoc = new Point(12, 37);

        button1.Location = new Point(12, button1.Location.Y + 25);

        TextBox newBoxx = new TextBox();
        newBoxx.Size = new Size(65, 20);
        newBoxx.Location = new Point(12, button1.Location.Y - 25);

        Controls.Add(newBoxx);
    }
```

I now want to be able to call and use the text entered into those boxes by the end user in a different method (i.e. another button click), but I run into errors relating to to the text box not existing in the context. So for the sake of simplicity lets say I wanted to press a button and change a lable to the text pulled from one of these boxes:

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lable1.Text = newBoxx.Text;
    }
```

How would I have to edit these, to allow for the use of newBoxx.text?

Comment: Does the click on button 1 create a new instance of button 2 each time as well, or is there only one instance of button 2? If there's only one instance of button 2, how do you determine which textbox's value to use?

Comment: or another one [C# Get text from a textbox that is made at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470178/c-sharp-get-text-from-a-textbox-that-is-made-at-runtime)

Comment: @BrentWaggoner There is only one instance of button 2, I wasn't quite sure how I was going to determine which value to use, as I said I'm still very new at this. Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: @Jim I took a look at some of those you linked me, and I think I figured it out, thank you.